How does an electron's distance from the nucleus depend on angular quantum number?
My school teacher told us this and I couldn't get his reason:

The average distance of an electron (belonging to the same orbit) from the nucleus decreases with the increase in the value of angular momentum quantum number for the orbital

I don't understand how l is related to the distance from the nucleus. I always thought it is the principal quantum number n that has a role in this.
I couldn't find any explanation in standard textbooks. Any help would be appreciated.

The orbit of electrons is misconception. The teacher must mean the same principal quantum number n.

You may want to review search results for site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu  orbital radial probability

Is there confusion between the most probable distance and the expectation value (mean, average) of the distance?

2s has a radial node while 2p doesn’t, so it’s hard to eyeball it.

It is further complicated that the relation of the orbital energy and the average electron distance to nucleus depends of the shape of radial probability function.


[OP] I don't understand how is l related to the distance from nucleus. I always thought it is the principal quantum number n that has a role in this

The first thing you learn is that the quantum number $l$ has to do with the shape of orbitals, e.g. "The orbital angular momentum quantum number l determines the shape of an orbital, and therefore the angular distribution." (source). However, the radial distribution does not only depend on $n$, but also on $l$.

[OP] I couldn't find any explanation in standard textbooks.Any help would be appreciated

It is possible that you will have to wait for a rigorous explanation. In many colleges, this is derived in Physcial Chemistry 2, in the third or fourth year of study, when students have taken sufficient math (calculus, differential equations, eigenvalues and eigenfunctions) to work through the solutions of the Schrödinger equation.
For a quick overview of the results, see e.g. here. Note that this is for a hydrogen atom (one electron) and its excited states. For multi-electron atoms that have 2s and 2p electrons (the first time you can compare different values of $l$), the theory is more complicated and there is no closed solution, i.e. you rely on approximate computational results.

[quoted by OP] The average distance of electron (belonging from the same orbit) from the nucleus decreases with the increase in the value of angular momentum quantum number for the orbital

As quoted, the statement is nonsensical. If you compare the expectation value of the nuclear distance of a 2s electron with that of a 2p electron (in a single-electron hydrogen atom), you find a larger distance for the 2p electron. If you are interested in the most probable distance (maximum of the radial distribution function), you find a larger value for the 2s electron. This is related to the 2s radial function having a node while the 2p radial function has none (instead, the angular function has a node).
